# Graph api. Not getting email field. Any other way of getting login username or email id?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using the graph API. I used below code for getting email id. But email id is returning as empty. Email-id is verified and is able to login with the testing account. Did I make any mistake? Permissions have been accepted.

```
login(){
   LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
               @Override
public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                                    Log.v("DEBUG",loginResult.getRecentlyDeniedPermissions()+" ACCEPTED PERMISSIONS :" +loginResult.getRecentlyGrantedPermissions());
                                    Log.v("DEBUG",response.toString());

                                    try {
                                        String email = object.getString("id");
                                        String name = object.getString("name");
                                        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                                        sessionLogin(email, name, "Facebook");
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        Log.e(TAG, "facebook onCompleted exception: ", e);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "id,first_name,name,last_name,email,gender,birthday");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();

}
```

Comment: Sure about this part, `String email = object.getString("id");` …? (The `id` field gets requested as well, so that at least should not result in an _empty_ string - but maybe it _gets_ emptied later on due to some part that actually tries to validate the value syntactically as an e-mail address …)

Comment: That was different actually. am not getting email field so i added user id field for the email address. I checked the received object in log. every requested parameter is present except email id. This is happening only for few accounts.

Comment: According to info from a Facebook engineer quite a while back (it was part of some bug report), there are some obscure combinations of privacy settings that prevent you from getting a user’s email, even if it is verified and the user granted your app permission. But since not all Facebook users even have an email in their profile (registered via mobile), you need an alternative for such cases anyway.